# RangeError (end): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1 when generating model

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, get-cli

Getting the error **RangeError (end): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1 when generating model** when I try to generate model

#### Expected Behavior

when I use this command `get generate model on match_details with assets/models/to_get/match_details.json`
it should be creating a model inside the `match_details` folder with the fields inside the JSON file mentioned.

#### Current Behavior

When I try to do this I get the error `RangeError (end): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1 when generating model** when I try to generate model`

#### Possible Solution

Am sure it is something about parsing the JSON file

#### More info

here is what the JSON file looks like

```json
{
    "success": true,
    "details": {
        "id": 22,
        "date_time": "2022-04-12T20:00:00Z",
        "home_team": {
            "id": 69,
            "home_strip": {
                "id": 15,
                "image": "/uploads/strip_5_0py3QXM.png"
            },
            "away_strip": {
                "id": 16,
                "image": "/uploads/WhatsApp_Image_2022-03-09_at_10.24.56_AM.jpeg"
            },
            "players": [{
                "id": 47,
                "is_cap": false,
                "average_skill": 3,
                "region": {
                    "id": 13,
                    "name_ar": "التجمع الخامس",
                    "name_en": "Fifth Settlement",
                    "state": {
                        "id": 8,
                        "name_ar": "القاهره",
                        "name_en": "Cairo"
                    }
                },
                "first_name": "Ezz El Din",
                "last_name": "Karim",
                "mobile": "01113481110",
                "email": null,
                "image": null,
                "positions_ar": [{
                    "مدافع": 3
                }],
                "positions_en": [{
                    "CB": 3
                }],
                "basic_skills_ar": [{
                        "السرعة": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "تمرير الكرة": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "تسديد": 2
                    }
                ],
                "basic_skills_en": [{
                        "speeding": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "Passing": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "shooting": 2
                    }
                ]
            }],
            "cap": {
                "id": 46,
                "is_cap": true,
                "average_skill": 3,
                "region": {
                    "id": 13,
                    "name_ar": "التجمع الخامس",
                    "name_en": "Fifth Settlement",
                    "state": {
                        "id": 8,
                        "name_ar": "القاهره",
                        "name_en": "Cairo"
                    }
                },
                "first_name": "Karim",
                "last_name": "Garrana",
                "mobile": "01113332257",
                "email": "karim.garrana@gmail.com",
                "image": null,
                "positions_ar": [{
                        "مهاجم": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "مدافع": 4
                    }
                ],
                "positions_en": [{
                        "ST": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "CB": 4
                    }
                ],
                "basic_skills_ar": [{
                        "السرعة": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "تمرير الكرة": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "تسديد": 3
                    }
                ],
                "basic_skills_en": [{
                        "speeding": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "Passing": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "shooting": 3
                    }
                ]
            },
            "average_skill": 3,
            "points": 0,
            "name": "كوبرا",
            "league": 25,
            "logo": "/uploads/9_IApeihR.png",
            "region_ar": "التجمع الخامس",
            "region_en": "Fifth Settlement"
        },
        "away_team": {
            "id": 68,
            "home_strip": {
                "id": 14,
                "image": "/uploads/strip_6.png"
            },
            "away_strip": {
                "id": 13,
                "image": "/uploads/strip_5.png"
            },
            "players": [{
                "id": 46,
                "is_cap": true,
                "average_skill": 3,
                "region": {
                    "id": 13,
                    "name_ar": "التجمع الخامس",
                    "name_en": "Fifth Settlement",
                    "state": {
                        "id": 8,
                        "name_ar": "القاهره",
                        "name_en": "Cairo"
                    }
                },
                "first_name": "Karim",
                "last_name": "Garrana",
                "mobile": "01113332257",
                "email": "karim.garrana@gmail.com",
                "image": null,
                "positions_ar": [{
                        "مهاجم": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "مدافع": 4
                    }
                ],
                "positions_en": [{
                        "ST": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "CB": 4
                    }
                ],
                "basic_skills_ar": [{
                        "السرعة": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "تمرير الكرة": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "تسديد": 3
                    }
                ],
                "basic_skills_en": [{
                        "speeding": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "Passing": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "shooting": 3
                    }
                ]
            }],
            "cap": {
                "id": 45,
                "is_cap": false,
                "average_skill": 4,
                "region": {
                    "id": 11,
                    "name_ar": "ميامى",
                    "name_en": "Miami",
                    "state": {
                        "id": 7,
                        "name_ar": "الإسكندرية",
                        "name_en": "Alexandria"
                    }
                },
                "first_name": "Ahmed",
                "last_name": "Wagdi",
                "mobile": "01207199086",
                "email": "ahmed.w.amin@gmail.com",
                "image": "/uploads/90f1e1c9-b430-4f9c-8347-a86be57f58676954964268664537546.jpg",
                "positions_ar": [{
                    "مدافع": 5
                }],
                "positions_en": [{
                    "CB": 5
                }],
                "basic_skills_ar": [{
                        "تسديد": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "تمرير الكرة": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "السرعة": 5
                    }
                ],
                "basic_skills_en": [{
                        "shooting": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "Passing": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "speeding": 5
                    }
                ]
            },
            "average_skill": 4,
            "points": 2,
            "name": "المنتقمون",
            "league": 25,
            "logo": "/uploads/6.png",
            "region_ar": "التجمع الخامس",
            "region_en": "Fifth Settlement"
        },
        "location": {
            "id": 8,
            "name_ar": "مدرسة الكابيتال",
            "name_en": "Capital School",
            "location": "30.014650515430546,31.4582347869873",
            "region": 13
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I figured the same issue, it was to do with one of the keys in the json, it started with a number (which is out of my control) - but doesn't seem to be an issue in your case. Could you post the whole error message - as it helped me find the issue in my case